# How to add a new jdbc interpreter to Zeppelin by editing its conf/interpreter.json file?

Tags: python, docker, jdbc, interpreter, apache-zeppelin

I successfully added a new JDBC interpreter to my preferred DB, by using the normal zeppelin UI. It works. My Zeppelin is running on a docker container on my machine. I noticed it added my interpreter configuration to /zeppelin/conf/interpreter.json file.

I extracted the piece of json that was inserted on the file, under interpreterSettings collection. I built a script that would programmatically add that json block to /zeppelin/conf/interpreter.json so that my container would start with that interpreter configured out of the box.

But after I run my script on a brand new Zeppelin container what happen is that:
 1) it works - the piece of json is successfully inserted into /zeppelin/conf/interpreter.json
 2) Zeppelin won't show my interpreter on its UI

What else must I do to programmatically add this interpreter to my Zeppelin container?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you approach will work in new version 0.8.0. In 0.8.0 interpreter ID equals interpreter name.
In previous versions interpreters have unique ID and this maybe reason of your question.

Remember that Zeppelin server must be off while editing `conf/interpreter.json`

Comment: Adding the new interpreter to the interpreter.json file works. I just need to restart the entire container. The problem is that I don't want to restart the entire container.  The container is ephemeral...

Answer (score 0):

My problem was happening because after the Zeppelin container started, it was already too late. Zeppelin service was up and running and it would have already loaded interpreter.json. So, what I did was to configure my Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT to a script of mine, overwriting the standard Zeppelin container's entry point. My script would do the injection of the additional configurations I needed on interpreter.json file and call /zeppelin/bin/zeppelin.sh to start zeppelin.

This way, I could do whatever I want with the configuration files BEFORE Zeppelin was actually started inside the container.

Kind regards,
AS

Comment: could you please share your dockerfile content here ? Thanks !